# Localhost extensions check

Tags: php, apache, localhost, mcrypt

I have to install big CMS on my localhost, but it requires mcrypt, and pdo_mysql. Before I've tried to install them, I've tried to access site, but I only got blank page. 
I'm running apache on windows, so I heard that I have to keep dll's in php extension folder. I've downloaded from dlldll.com (it's not ad) files php_pdo_mysql.dll, and php_mcrypt.php. 
In php.ini I've uncommented  lines "extension=php_mcrypt.dll", and "extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll". I've restarted apache... Blank again. And what now?

This is my get_loaded_extensions:

```
Array
(
[0] => bcmath
[1] => calendar
[2] => com_dotnet
[3] => ctype
[4] => session
[5] => filter
[6] => ftp
[7] => hash
[8] => iconv
[9] => json
[10] => odbc
[11] => pcre
[12] => Reflection
[13] => date
[14] => libxml
[15] => standard
[16] => tokenizer
[17] => zlib
[18] => SimpleXML
[19] => dom
[20] => SPL
[21] => wddx
[22] => xml
[23] => xmlreader
[24] => xmlwriter
[25] => apache2handler
[26] => curl
[27] => gd
[28] => mbstring
[29] => mysql
[30] => mysqli
[31] => rar
[32] => zip
[33] => eAccelerator
)
```

What I did wrong?

Update:

Some progress - now I have PHP startup warning on apache restart. "Unble to load php_mcrypt.dll/php_pdo_mysql.dll" - but I have those files in this directory. Is it possible that corrupted are for PHP same as non existing?

Comment: Did you definitely uncomment the entries in the correct php.ini. It's quite common to find several copies of the file in different directories.

Comment: I've installed WebServ, and opened it through shorcut. Also I've changed at the same time root directory.

Comment: Turn on your full error reporting.. that should give you more info on whether it's not finding the DLL's, they have the wrong permissions, or if it's something else entirely.

Comment: The error message you quote sounds like the DLL was for the wrong PHP version.

Comment: I think that PHP version is diffrent from DLL versions - My PHP 5.2.6.6, mcrypt.dll - 5.2.13.13, pdo_mysql.dll - 5.3.2.0. I can't find 5.2.6.6 versions.

Full errors: 

1. PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'PATH' - The specified module could not be found.

2. PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'PATH' - The specified procedure could not be found. I've tried to translate as best as I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you have following two options set in php.ini
By default error reporting is Off and you get blank page.

- error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
- display_errors = On

Comment: I had deinstalled Webserv and installed newest XAMPP - it has those Lib's.